# How to convert a string 'Y-m-d h-m-s' to timestruct 'Y-m-d' in python

Tags: python

I have the following dates in a json file that look something like this

```
dataset = [{'date': '2017-01-27 21:56:57'}]
```

**How do I convert it to a timeStruct it so that it just gives me '2017-01-27'?**

Using the following code...

```
import json
import time

for d in dataset:
    d['timeStruct'] = time.strptime(d['date'], '%Y-%m-%d')
```

...gives me an error `ValueError: unconverted data remains:  05:21:16`

Is there a way to convert to Y-m-d without slicing the hour, minute, second part off? In SQL it automatically converts it based on the `'%Y-%m-%d'`

Comment: if the dataset, only contains 1 item, then why loop thrugh it?

Comment: What does `strptime` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dateutil` module.

```
import dateutil

dataset = [{'date': '2017-01-27 21:56:57'}]

for d in dataset:
    d['timeStruct'] = dateutil.parser.parse(d['date']).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

print(dataset)
```

Output:

```
[{'date': '2017-01-27 21:56:57', 'timeStruct': '2017-01-27'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the @Peter Wood the answer is improved.

You could use `'{:%Y-%m-%d}'.format(t)`

```
from datetime import datetime

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dataset = [{'date': '2017-01-27 21:56:57'}]
    for d in dataset:
        d['timeStruct'] = '{:%Y-%m-%d}'.format(datetime.strptime(d['date'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

The t variable:

```
2017-1-27
```

Comment: Format strings and datetime play together nicely: [pyformat.info#datetime](https://pyformat.info/#datetime). e.g. `'{:%Y-%m-%d}'.format(t)`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment, did I miss something in the answer?

Comment: Your result `t` was crafted by hand, converting each part to a `str` and adding them all together. You can create a format `{:%Y-%m-%d}` which is easier for a human to read and comprehend.

Comment: Thank you, sir, I will do my best to improve the answer. Regards

Answer (score 1):

You have to first convert it to a tuple with `strptime()` and then format it to a string again with `strftime()`:

```
dataset = [{'date': '2017-01-27 21:56:57'}]
for d in dataset:
    timetuple = time.strptime(d['date'],"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    d['timeStruct'] = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d",timetuple)

print(dataset)

>> [{'date': '2017-01-27 21:56:57', 'timeStruct': '2017-01-27'}]
```